# How to encrypt messages with ECC in pycryptodom

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I'm using Hybrid encryption(RSA+AES) but the length was large and now i want to use ECC instead of RSA, but in pycryptodom there is no implementation for that..
this is my RSA code

```
def generate_keys():
    key = RSA.generate(1024)
    private_key = key.exportKey(format='PEM', pkcs=8, 
                  protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
    f = open("private_key.pem", "wb")
    f.write(private_key)
    public_key = key.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
    f = open("public_key.pem", "wb")
    f.write(public_key)
    f.close()

def encrypt(username, msg):
    #get the reciever's public key
    f = open("{}.pem".format(username)) # a.salama.pem
    recipient_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())
    f.close()

    # Encrypt the session key with the reciever's public RSA key
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)

    # Encrypt the data with the AES session key
    session_key = get_random_bytes(16)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(msg.encode('utf-
                    8'))
    encrypted_data = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key) + 
    cipher_aes.nonce + tag +  ciphertext    
    encrypted_data = base64.b64encode(encrypted_data)
    return encrypted_data
```

And after trying to use ECC+AES the code will be

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
import base64

def generate_keys():
    key = ECC.generate(curve='P-256') #3072 RSA 
    private_key = key.export_key(format='PEM')
    f = open('private_key.pem','wt')
    f.write(private_key)
    f.close()

    public_key = key.public_key().export_key(format='PEM')
    f = open('public_key.pem','wt')
    f.write(public_key)
    f.close()

def encrypt(username, msg):
    #get the reciever's public key
    f = open("{}.pem".format(username), 'rt') # a.salama.pem
    recipient_key = ECC.import_key(f.read())
    f.close()

    # Encrypt the session key with the reciever's public RSA key
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)

    # Encrypt the data with the AES session key
    session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
    #we use the EAX mode to allow detection of unauthorized 
    modifications.  
    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(msg.encode('utf-
                      8'))
    encrypted_data = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key) + 
    cipher_aes.nonce + tag +  ciphertext    
    encrypted_data = base64.b64encode(encrypted_data)

    return encrypted_data.decode()
```

This gives me error in this line

```
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
```

but i want to encrypt the session key with the public key, how to do this with pycryptodome or any other way

Comment: Can you post the solution? if you ever found it...

Comment: The Pycryptodom itself didn't make a code for the ECC, I think it is under maintenance. So, unfortunately, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Pycryptodome **does not support** elliptic curve-based encryption (ECC encryption).

Use the **[ECIES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_curve_integrated_encryption_scheme)** algorithm instead, e.g. this Python library: https://github.com/kigawas/eciespy

The **ECIES** (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme) is **hybrid encryption scheme**, which combines **ECC public-key cryptography** to asymmetrically encrypt a session key, used later to encrypt the input data with a **symmetric cipher** (e.g. with AES-GCM).

Comment: This answer is now deprecated, Pycryptodome now supports ECC, see https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/ecc.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but to anyone else that comes here:

You can use Pycryptodome or Cryptography for this now. Using Pycrptodome for example:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC

def get_or_create_public_key(filename: str = "private_key.pem"):
""" Helper function to retrieve public key """
   private_key_file = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, filename)
   if os.path.exists(private_key_file):
      file = open(private_key_file, "rt")
      private_key = ECC.import_key(file.read(), passphrase=settings.SECRET_KEY)
   else:
      private_key = ECC.generate(curve="P-256")
      file = open(private_key_file, "wt")
      file.write(
         private_key.export_key(
            format="PEM",
            use_pkcs8=True,
            passphrase=settings.SECRET_KEY,
            protection="PBKDF2WithHMAC-SHA1AndAES128-CBC",
        )
      )
      file.close()
   public_key = private_key.public_key()
   return public_key.export_key(format="PEM")
```

Comment: This doesn't actually help. The problem is creating a PKCS1_OAEP cipher with a ECC key. Which currently results in an "AttributeError: 'EccKey' object has no attribute 'n'".

Comment: This answer just shows how to generate a keypair which is not what the question asks for. Encryption and Decryption is still unsupported by PyCryptodome